# Not able to access the service url from client server .Error :<urlopen error [Errorno 10060]>

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, wcftestclient

we have few services hosted on the server and they are being consumed by the client.

The service URL be like this-
http://10.xx.x.y:80xx/sample.svc

The server where they are hosted , i tried to access the url and it works fine and even tried to invoke a method and that too worked file for a source to destinationn data transfer.

The problem is the people who use these SERVICES in SOAP are getting the below error :

```
Verification failed: Error resolving WSDL:
http://10.xx.x.y:80xx/sample.svc?wsdl. Error :<urlopen error [Errorno 10060].A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 
after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond>
```

link of th error image: https://ibb.co/NTtWdgb

```
Error :<urlopen error [Errorno 10060].A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond  after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond>
```

Comment: IP Addresses starting with 10. are private IPs. You might need to get the external IP address of your service if it's accessed outside of your network

Comment: hi.. yes they are private ip and are only been accessed within that network

Comment: Must be a blocked port then? Firewall incoming traffic settings for port 80xx? (the port you're using)?

Comment: To exclude the network issue, can you access the service description page in the browser of the client machine?
http://10.xx.x.y:80xx/sample.svc?wsdl
Alternatively, the service start page.
http://10.xx.x.y:80xx/sample.svc
At last, I would like that you could share the server configuration details with me.